# Метод в javascript

Tags: javascript, функции, классы

Правильно ли утверждение, что метод в `js` — это функция в классе?

Comment: в переводе книги с носрогом фланагана методом емнип называют любую функцию вызыванную с указанием контекста (через точку или через apply например), а вот как оно на самом деле с теоретической точки зрения, большой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Да, метод - это функция в классе. А вот применимо ли это понятие в js, где и классов-то как таковых нет - большой вопрос.